# How do I use inches with snap svg?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I have just started playing around with snap and have been trying to work in inches instead of pixels, is this possible? If so how do I go about using inches? It seems that some functions accept inches and some don't?

```
// This works
var s = Snap("1.5in", "1.5in");

// This works
s.rect("0in", "0in", "1.5in", "1.5in").attr({
    stroke: "#f00",
    fill: "transparent"
});

// This works
s.path("M0,144L144,0").attr({
    stroke: "#f00"
});

// This fails (Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M0in,0inL1.5in,1.5in")
s.path("M0in,0inL1.5in,1.5in").attr({
    stroke: "#f00"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, certain SVG values only accept raw numbers (interpretted as SVG user coordinates), not lengths with units.  The path "d" attribute is one of those.

That is not a snap.svg issue, that's how the underlying SVG elements work.

The easiest approach would be to create for yourself a conversion factor.  The initial value for SVG user coordinates is that 1 user unit equals one CSS "px" (pixel) unit.  **By CSS standards, a "px" unit is exactly equal to 1/96th of an "in" (inch) unit.**  If you scale your SVG with transforms or a viewBox attribute, all the [length units](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/data_types/length) scale accordingly, so the ratio remains constant.

Therefore, to create a path equivalent to `"M0in,0inL1.5in,1.5in"`, you would multiply each number by 96 and then concatenate the string together:

```
s.path("M0,0L" + 1.5*96 + "," + 1.5*96).attr({
    stroke: "#f00"
});
```

If you've got a long and complex path to create, it's worth mentioning that [`Array.join("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is more efficient than the `+` operator for joining a long list of strings and numbers into one string.

However, **be aware that the CSS/SVG "in" unit won't always display on screen as exactly an inch**.  If you're printing the document, it should be pretty accurate.  But of course, if you're scaling or transforming your SVG, it might not be anywhere close to an inch.

Comment: Well I guess I went down the correct path, I created a function that I use for all measurements to convert fractions into pixels.  Seems to work well with my demo but will have to test it for out performance.